# How to create CloudWatch logs trigger for AWS Lambda using aws ruby SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I know there should be a way to create trigger for AWS Lambda using aws ruby sdk (just like it is possible to do it using AWS Management Console).

*Update, I was able to find out a way to create trigger. I'm using following code to do that:

```
@cloudwatchlogs = Aws::CloudWatchLogs::Client.new(region: region, credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key))
@cloudwatchlogs.put_subscription_filter({
   log_group_name: "RDSOSMetrics",
   filter_name: "RDS metrics filter",
   filter_pattern: "RDS metrics filter pattern",
   destination_arn: function_arn
})
```

I'm getting following error while trying to do that:

```
*** Aws::CloudWatchLogs::Errors::InvalidParameterException Exception: Could not execute the lambda function. Make sure you have given CloudWatch Logs permission to execute your function
```

Just for the sake of testing it out, I have role X which is attached to Lambda function and that role has AWSLambdaFullAccess policy added to it, but I'm still getting this error.

Anything else I'm missing

Thanks,
Bakir

Comment: Can you clarify what sort of 'CloudWatch trigger' you're wanting to add? That is a bit ambiguous; you could add a cloudwatch event (schedule) trigger, a cloudwatch log trigger, or an SNS trigger based on a published message via cloudwatch alarms. That detail will change the scope of the answer.

Comment: Updated my response. In general, in my case I need cloudwatch log trigger for lambda function

Answer (score 6):

CloudWatch Logs permissions can be added with:

```
client.add_permission({
    action: "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    function_name: function_arn,
    principal: "logs." + region + ".amazonaws.com",
    source_account: account_id,
    source_arn: "arn:aws:logs:" + region + ":" + account_id + ":log-group:" + log_group_name + ":*",
    statement_id: unique_identifier,
})
```

Where:

- **function_arn** is your function identifier similar to `arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:111111111111:function:yourFunctionName`
- **region** is name of your service region similar to `eu-west-1`
- **account_id** is id of your account similar to `111111111111`
- **log_group_name** is name of logs you will be streaming from similar to `/aws/lambda/logGroupName`
- **unique_identifier** some random string to be used in policy statement. E.g. `ID-1`

---

It should be executed in following sequence:

- Create Lambda function and Log group
- **Add permissions**
- Put subscription filter

---

More information:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Lambda/Client.html#add_permission-instance_method
- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-permission.html

---

**Note** the asterisk symbol at the end of `source_arn`:

```
arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:111111111111:log-group:logGroup:*
arn:aws:logs:eu-west-1:111111111111:log-group:logGroup
```

It is `arn` of log streams, not `arn` of log group.
It took me some time to debug this one (until I found error with `aws lambda get-policy`)

Comment: a note: the client is a CloudWatch client - not a Lambda client.